# Range of a regular expression match ignoring case and diacritics in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am trying to figure out how to find a range of a regular expression match in a string. The search needs to be both case and diacritics insensitive. I've tried using something like this:

```
"München".rangeOfString(
    "[mno][tuv][mno]",
    options: [
        .RegularExpressionSearch,
        .DiacriticInsensitiveSearch,
        .CaseInsensitiveSearch],
    range: nil,
    locale: nil)
```

but it looks like `.RegularExpressionSearch` doesn't work along with `.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch`.

---

I've tried using the `stringByFolding` method to transform the string before the search. The problem with this method is that it transforms `ß` into `ss`, thus changing the length of the string and potentially invalidating the result range.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a regular expression be diacritical insensitive, unless you write the expression that way. The definitive reference is the [unicode regular expression standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Hex_Notation_and_Normalization).The example there shows how to normalize characters for the match. You'll have to explicitly list them, but that is the only way I know of to do it.

Regex engines supporting unicode can choose to normalize strings before matching. I couldn't find any documentation saying if Apple/ICU does this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, regarding `String.CompareOptions.regularExpression`:

> ...
>   If set, no other options can apply except `caseInsensitive` and
>   `anchored`. ...

So you cannot combine `diacriticInsensitive` with `regularExpression` option.

In order to achieve a regular expression that is diacritic insensitive, you can use the Unicode category `\p{L}` to match characters that are letters. More Unicode categories can be found here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html